# Two different functions one works one calls a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have two functions `getCompanyDetails` and `getHostingDetails`

The first database `getCompanyDetails` works fine but the `getHostingDetails` shows

`Trying to get property of non-object`

**getCompanyDetails:**

*Controller:*  `$data['companyName'] = $this->quote->getCompanyDetails()->companyName;`

*Model:*

```
public function getCompanyDetails()
{
    $this->db->select('companyName,companySlogan,companyContact,
                       companyEmail,companyWebsite,companyPhone,
                       companyFax,companyAddress');

    $this->db->from('companyDetails');
    $result = $this->db->get();

    if($result->num_rows()<1)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }else{
        return $result->row();
    }
}
```

**getHostingDetails:**

*Controller:*

`$data['hostingRequired'] = $this->quote->getHostingDetails()->hostingRequired;`

*Model:*

```
public function getHostingDetails()
{
    $this->db->select('hostingRequired,domainRequired,domainToBeReged,
                       domaintoBeReged0,domainTransfer,domainToBeTransfered,
                       domainToBeTransfered0,currentHosting');

    $this->db->from('hostingDetails');
    $result = $this->db->get();

    if($result->num_rows()<1)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }else{
        return $result->row();
    }               
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, one method returns an object from `$result->row()` and the other `false`. You can't call a method on `false`.

`false` is returned when no record is found. So you need to check the return value before using it.

Comment: :) How could I display an error message?  I have a fair idea its another if statement

Answer (score 1):

Well in your `get` functions chances is your code might return you `false` if there is no rows returned. You might want to check before retrieving the details.  Example:

```
$details = $this->quote->getHostingDetails();
if($details){
    $data['hostingRequired'] = $details->hostingRequired;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably how you use those functions in your controller. If any of them returns FALSE, then

```
$this->quote->getHostingDetails()->hostingRequired;
```

is going to give you errors. Try

```
if ($row = $this->quote->getHostingDetails()) {
    echo $row->hostingRequired;
}
```